# Integrate CkEditor with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, fckeditor

I extracted ckeditor in `js/ckeditor` and added the source to view as well:

```
$javascript->link(array('jquery','functions','pngfix','ckeditor/ckeditor'))
```

Then nothing will happen to the textarea and it just disappears.
The version is CakePHP v1.2
please help me.

Comment: I guess you also need to include some CSS? Or is it included via JS? Please check your browser's console to see if you have any 404's (or other non 2xx responses).

Comment: can you show `textarea` element code, there you want to show up ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by adding `ckeditor` class name to textarea

Answer (score 0):

Editor in website is so important to make the content more beautiful, so we will see how integration CKEditor and CKFinder with cakephp 2.x.

[image]

Creating editor helper:
EditorHelper.php

```
<?php
class EditorHelper extends Helper
{
 function loadCK($id){
 $buff = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
 //<![CDATA[
 var editor_$id = CKEDITOR.replace('$id', {customConfig : '/js/editor/config.js'});
 CKFinder.SetupCKEditor( editor_$id, '/js/ckfinder/' );
 //]]>
 </script>";
 return $buff;
 }
}
?>
```

Second we will call it in controller :

```
<?php
    public $helpers = array('Editor');
?>
```

Third we will creating the view :
form.ctp

```
<script src="/js/editor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/ckfinder/ckfinder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<?php echo $this->Form->textarea('Item.content', array('size' => '32')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Editor->loadCK ('PagetextContent');  ?>
```

And After download ckeditor and ckfinder from source http://ckeditor.com and we will put them in /webroot/js/ folder.

That's it, Hope it's helpful.